# wordpress - Ajax refuses to work in plugin

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I've been reading questions about this problem for a little over a week now, and have tweaked my code to try every answer but have not found a working solution yet. I created a very basic plugin and at this point, I'm just trying to get the response to come through. Here's what I have starting with the main php file:

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'letsgo');

function letsgo() {
   wp_register_script('profile', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__ ) . 'js/profile.js', array('jquery'));
   wp_localize_script('profile', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));        
   wp_enqueue_script('profile');
}

function tecprofile() {
    $result = array(
        'verify' => 'yes'
    );
    echo json_encode($result);
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_tecprofile', 'tecprofile');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_tecprofile', 'tecprofile');
?>
```

And profile.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
            data: {action: 'tecprofile'},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                    console.log(response.verify);
            },

            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    });
```

All I get in the console is "error."
Any advice or help would be huge, thanks!

Comment: Why not log `status` and `error` so you can actually see some details, ie `console.error(status, error)`? You can also use your dev-tools _Network_ panel to inspect the request and response

Comment: @Phil I'll do that right now!

Comment: @Phil weird.. as soon as I added that, I got "yes" in the console